# Magento Untranslate specific pages

Tags: javascript, php, magento

We have Magento website with six Websites and six Store View in each for different languages. The site is supposed to be translated when the user is logged-in only and everything outside login must be in English only. The issue now is that the site translate those specific pages when the user is logged-out. How do I untranslate these pages and the pages validaions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the translate function is a js file. You can unset it out of root / default and instantiate it again under the customer_logged_in slug.  I'm unsure of your level of knowledge on Magento Blocks if you need a more detailed answer let me know.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry, I inverted your request.  Glad you figured it out.  Sorry about not getting back to you quickly!